# Can I assign value to target of reference in PHP? (I want to dereference)

Tags: php, arrays, reference

I have a nested array, and I have a reference to an element within that array. I would like to be able to assign a value inside that array using my reference, but I can't see how to do that.

```php
$arr = ['foo' => ['bar' => 'Hello World']];
$ref =& $arr['foo']['bar'];

var_export($arr);
//  array (
//    'foo' => 
//    array (
//      'bar' => 'Hello World',
//    ),
//  )

var_export($ref);
//  'Hello World'

$arr['foo']['bar'] = 'Test';
var_export($ref);
//  'Test'
```

The above works fine, but I now want to *assign* a new value to 'bar' using my reference:

```php
&$ref = 'fooz';
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '&', expecting end of file in php shell code on line 1
```

I tried this, but it's a nope:

```php
$ref =& 'fooz';
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) in php shell code on line 1
```

And slightly worryingly, attempting this assignment appears to corrupt data:

```php
$ref &= 'fooz';
var_export($ref);
//  '@elh'

var_export($arr);
//  array (
//    'foo' => 
//    array (
//      'bar' => '@elh',
//    ),
//  )
```

Background: I have an array that may or may not be nested, and thus it's kind of hard to find the leaf-node where I want to assign things. So I had hoped to get a reference to said leaf-node, and then everything would be lovely.

I have PHP running on Linux Mint 20.2 (64bit).

```sh
$ php --version
PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: Jul  5 2021 15:13:35) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Additional 20210907-1518:
I am using the following function to set my reference:

```php
function &getNestedArrayRef($array, array $keys) {                                                                    
  $key = array_shift($keys);                                                                                        
  if (!is_null($key)) {                                                                                             
    return getNestedArrayRef($array[$key], $keys);                                                                
  }                                                                                                                 
  return $array;                                                                                                    
}

$ref = &getNestedArrayRef($arr, ['foo', 'bar]);

// The above _should_ be equivalent to:
$ref =& $arr['foo']['bar'];
```

^ it's entirely *possible* this isn't working as intended!

However, without it, it's kind of tricky to get a reference to an arbitrary point within the array without a literal reference.

Comment: You mention not wanting a literal reference, but what then is `['foo', 'bar]`

Comment: That ['foo', 'bar'] is a simple non-keyed array that I obtain using yet another function to find a leaf-node in the array; the depth of the original array ($arr) is arbitrary. I *have* used a literal here, but it is just for example... I could post it (the _other_ function) here, but it's a bit of a rats-nest to be honest and I don't think it would help.

Comment: Was the second attempt not better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you are making life too complex.

Using the `=&` makes `$ref` a reference, so you dont need to use the `&` reference idea on it again.

```
$arr = ['foo' => ['bar' => 'Hello World']];
$ref =& $arr['foo']['bar'];

$ref = 'Hi Boyo';
var_dump($arr);
```

RESULT

```
array(1) {
  'foo' => array(1) {
    'bar' => string(7) "Hi Boyo"
  }
}
```

**Second try**, when real code was involved

```
$arr = ['foo' => ['bar' => 'Hello World']];

function &getNestedArrayRef(&$array, array $keys) {                                                                    
    $key = array_shift($keys);                                                                                        
    if (!is_null($key)) {  
        return getNestedArrayRef($array[$key], $keys);                                                                
    }
    return $array;                                                                                                   
}
  
$ref =& getNestedArrayRef($arr, ['foo', 'bar']);

$ref = 'Bye';
print_r($arr);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [foo] => Array
        (
            [bar] => Bye
        )

)
```

You also need to pass the array to the function by reference

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Your example does work perfectly, but when I try it with my own code, it still doesn't work as intended. (UPDATE: apologies - I hit return by mistake, didn't realise I could edit, then added another comment below!!)

Comment: Ok so add some specific 'real life' code to your question where it does not work

Comment: ...I've added to the end of my question with a function I'm using to get a reference to part of the array. When I use this function, it doesn't work. But if I assign a reference to a literal part of the array, then it does work.

Comment: That bent my brian for a while :) But have a go with that

Comment: You are my hero!! :D

Thanks *absolutely loads* for figuring this out - I really appreciate it!